# Run a setInterval function, stop it for 3 seconds and continue running it

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a setInterval function going trough some div classes, if it finds a div with a particular class it should stop for 3 seconds and then continue running. Notice how I am using:

```
   clearInterval(myInterval);
```

but I need something else, to start the sequence again or make it to continue running from there.

e.g:

```
var myInterval =  setInterval(function() {
                    move.removeClass( "girlFromRight" );

                    runFromRight -= 9;
                    move = $("#grid"+ runFromRight);
                    move.addClass("girlFromRight");


                    if (move.hasClass("man") === true ||
                        move.hasClass("man-right") === true ||
                        move.hasClass("man-left") === true )
                        {


                          clearInterval(myInterval);


                          move.addClass('inLove');
                          move.removeClass('girlFromRight');

                          setTimeout(function() {
                          move.removeClass('inLove');
                          move.addClass('man');

                          }, 3000);


                    }


                    if (c == 9){
                      clearInterval(myInterval);
                    }
                    }, 300);


                   keyPressed = false;

        }, randomTime);
        }
```

Comment: Why not use *setTimeout* and set the interval to the required amount after each run, so 300 or 3000 depending on the test.

Comment: Are you looking for .delay() https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: I am developing a video game. This is like a girl that appears and stuns a man for 3 seconds, but the man is not always in the same place. That is why I use setInvertal in order to make her go over all grids until she finds him.

Comment: @Evrard-c I think .delay() is not what I need.

Comment: If you extract the function you are calling into a named function, you can `clearInterval` it and then just `setInterval` it again afterwards... Would that be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using *setTimeout* and setting the interval (300 or 3000) after each run based on a test. That way you don't have to start and stop *setInterval*.

A quick example is below, it highlights each div in sequence, pausing longer on any where the text content is evenly divisible by 3 (as an example test).

```js
function doLoop(){
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  var i = 0;
  function loop(){
    var selected = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
    [].forEach.call(selected,function(el) {
      el.className = 'notSelected';
    });
    divs[i].className = 'selected';
    setTimeout(loop, divs[i].textContent % 3? 300 : 3000);
    i = ++i % (divs.length - 2);
  }
  loop();
}

window.onload = doLoop;
```

```css
.notSelected{}
.selected{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="notSelected">0</div>
<div class="notSelected">1</div>
<div class="notSelected">2</div>
<div class="notSelected">3</div>
<div class="notSelected">4</div>
<div class="notSelected">5</div>
```

Comment: How could I better apply this to my scenario?

Comment: @randseed1724—if you want that, you need to post a [***minimal**, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question, preferably as a runnable snippet.